# XML parsing w/PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse this XML file, and I can move around it no problem using this method:

```
 $nfl_futures_url = 'thisurl.xml'; 

 $nfl_futures_xml = simplexml_load_file($nfl_futures_url);

$nfl_futures_loop = $nfl_futures_xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market[0]->participant[5]['name'];  (Which returns Buffalo Bills)
```

My problem is that I can't access the second < type > tag group. I have tried this:

```
response->williamhill->class->type['name']['NCAA']->market[0]participant[5]['name'];
```

But I can only access the first  fields and their attributes. I have also tried various combinations such as:

```
 response->williamhill->class->type[1]->market[0]participant[5]['name'];
```

But still nothing. I know I'm missing something very small, any help would be appreciated.

```
 <response request="getHierarchyByMarketType" code="001" message="success" debug="" provider="williamhill">
    <williamhill>
    <class id="19" name="American Football" maxRepDate="2017-04-04" maxRepTime="00:51:59">
    <type id="195" name="NFL" url="http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/betting/t/195" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:32:33">
    <market id="443609414" name="Super Bowl LII Winner - Super Bowl Outright" url="http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/e/10542693/Super%2dBowl%2dLII%2dWinner" date="2017-08-01" time="12:00:00" betTillDate="2017-08-01" betTillTime="12:00:00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:36:07" placeAvailable="N" forcastAvailable="N" tricastAvailable="N" eachwayAvailable="Y" cashoutAvailable="N" startingPriceAvailable="N" livePriceAvailable="Y" guarenteedPriceAvailable="N" firstPriceAvailable="N" ewPlaces="2" ewReduction="1/2">
    <participant name="Tampa Bay Buccaneers" id="1442304358" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="New York Jets" id="1442304374" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="New Orleans Saints" id="1442304359" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Miami Dolphins" id="1442304375" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Carolina Panthers" id="1442304360" odds="28/1" oddsDecimal="29.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Buffalo Bills" id="1442304376" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Denver Broncos" id="1442304361" odds="18/1" oddsDecimal="19.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Baltimore Ravens" id="1442304377" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Los Angeles Chargers" id="1442304362" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Pittsburgh Steelers" id="1442304378" odds="12/1" oddsDecimal="13.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Kansas City Chiefs" id="1442304363" odds="25/1" oddsDecimal="26.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Cincinnati Bengals" id="1442304379" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Oakland Raiders" id="1442304364" odds="14/1" oddsDecimal="15.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Cleveland Browns" id="1442304380" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Los Angeles Rams" id="1442304365" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Minnesota Vikings" id="1442304381" odds="28/1" oddsDecimal="29.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Arizona Cardinals" id="1442304366" odds="28/1" oddsDecimal="29.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Green Bay Packers" id="1442304382" odds="10/1" oddsDecimal="11.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="San Francisco 49ers" id="1442304367" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Chicago Bears" id="1442304383" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Seattle Seahawks" id="1442304368" odds="12/1" oddsDecimal="13.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Detroit Lions" id="1442304384" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Indianapolis Colts" id="1442304370" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Washington Redskins" id="1442304386" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Houston Texans" id="1442304371" odds="22/1" oddsDecimal="23.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="New York Giants" id="1442304385" odds="25/1" oddsDecimal="26.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Dallas Cowboys" id="1442304387" odds="9/1" oddsDecimal="10.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Tennessee Titans" id="1442304369" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Jacksonville Jaguars" id="1442304372" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Philadelphia Eagles" id="1442304388" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Atlanta Falcons" id="1442304357" odds="8/1" oddsDecimal="9.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="New England Patriots" id="1442304373" odds="5/1" oddsDecimal="6.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:52:01" handicap=""/>
    </market>
    </type>
    <type id="265" name="NCAA" url="http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/betting/t/265" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:32:33">
    <market id="434945242" name="2017 Heisman Trophy Winner - Heisman Trophy Winner" url="http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/e/10349611/2017%2dHeisman%2dTrophy%2dWinner" date="2017-08-01" time="12:00:01" betTillDate="2017-08-01" betTillTime="12:00:01" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:36:07" placeAvailable="N" forcastAvailable="N" tricastAvailable="N" eachwayAvailable="N" cashoutAvailable="N" startingPriceAvailable="N" livePriceAvailable="Y" guarenteedPriceAvailable="N" firstPriceAvailable="N">
    <participant name="Jake Browning (Washington)" id="1413969729" odds="10/1" oddsDecimal="11.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Luke Falk (Washington St)" id="1442879419" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:41" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Christian Kirk (Texas A&M)" id="1413969757" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Calvin Ridley (Alabama)" id="1414048903" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Arden Key (LSU)" id="1413969755" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Nick Fitzgerald (Mississippi St)" id="1417089361" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Kamryn Pettway (Auburn)" id="1413969759" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Saquon Barkley (Penn St)" id="1413969750" odds="20/1" oddsDecimal="21.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Derrius Guice (LSU)" id="1413969727" odds="25/1" oddsDecimal="26.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Bo Scarborough (Alabama)" id="1442879227" odds="20/1" oddsDecimal="21.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Mason Rudolph (Oklahoma St)" id="1442877437" odds="16/1" oddsDecimal="17.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:34" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Josh Rosen (UCLA)" id="1413969747" odds="16/1" oddsDecimal="17.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Jalen Hurts (Alabama)" id="1413969735" odds="20/1" oddsDecimal="21.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Trace McSorley (Penn St)" id="1413969737" odds="14/1" oddsDecimal="15.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="JT Barrett (Ohio St)" id="1413969753" odds="12/1" oddsDecimal="13.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Sam Darnold (USC)" id="1413969743" odds="6/1" oddsDecimal="7.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Lamar Jackson (Louisville)" id="1413969723" odds="7/1" oddsDecimal="8.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Baker Mayfield (Oklahoma)" id="1413969741" odds="7/1" oddsDecimal="8.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-12" lastUpdateTime="20:22:33" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Jacob Eason (Georgia)" id="1519795997" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-05" lastUpdateTime="22:58:26" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Nick Chubb (Georgia)" id="1417089110" odds="25/1" oddsDecimal="26.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Jerod Evans (Virginia Tech)" id="1417089237" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Derwin James (Florida)" id="1417089362" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Wilton Speight (Michigan)" id="1417089363" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Will Grier (Florida)" id="1417089248" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Ed Oliver (Houston)" id="1413969740" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Brandon Wimbush (Notre Dame)" id="1417089394" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Deondre Francois (FSU)" id="1413969733" odds="12/1" oddsDecimal="13.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Shane Buechele (Texas)" id="1413969731" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    </market>
    <market id="434950542" name="2017/18 College Football Championship Outright - College Football Championship Outright" url="http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/e/10349636/2017%2f18%2dCollege%2dFootball%2dChampionship%2dOutright" date="2017-08-01" time="12:00:01" betTillDate="2017-08-01" betTillTime="12:00:01" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:36:07" placeAvailable="N" forcastAvailable="N" tricastAvailable="N" eachwayAvailable="Y" cashoutAvailable="N" startingPriceAvailable="N" livePriceAvailable="Y" guarenteedPriceAvailable="N" firstPriceAvailable="N" ewPlaces="2" ewReduction="1/2">
    <participant name="Illinois" id="1413990259" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Missouri" id="1413990284" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Oklahoma State" id="1413990300" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Washington" id="1413990338" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Texas A&M" id="1413990322" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Utah" id="1413990332" odds="80/1" oddsDecimal="81.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Purdue" id="1413990306" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Arizona" id="1413990221" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="BYU" id="1413990233" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Florida Atlantic" id="1413990249" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Minnesota" id="1413990281" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Colorado" id="1413990242" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Auburn" id="1413990226" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Wake Forest" id="1413990337" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Texas" id="1413990321" odds="28/1" oddsDecimal="29.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Pittsburgh" id="1413990305" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="South Florida" id="1413990313" odds="150/1" oddsDecimal="151.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Maryland" id="1413990273" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Houston" id="1413990257" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Clemson" id="1413990241" odds="20/1" oddsDecimal="21.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="South Carolina" id="1413990312" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Notre Dame" id="1413990296" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Virginia Tech" id="1413990336" odds="40/1" oddsDecimal="41.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Tennessee" id="1413990320" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Penn State" id="1413990304" odds="25/1" oddsDecimal="26.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="California" id="1413990234" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Kansas State" id="1413990264" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Florida" id="1413990248" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Cincinnati" id="1413990240" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Kentucky" id="1413990266" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Virginia" id="1413990335" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Temple" id="1413990319" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Oregon State" id="1413990303" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Wisconsin" id="1413990343" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Louisville" id="1413990271" odds="16/1" oddsDecimal="17.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Georgia Tech" id="1413990255" odds="200/1" oddsDecimal="201.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Ole Miss" id="1413990282" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Arkansas" id="1413990223" odds="200/1" oddsDecimal="201.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Vanderbilt" id="1413990334" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Syracuse" id="1413990318" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Oregon" id="1413990302" odds="80/1" oddsDecimal="81.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Nebraska" id="1413990286" odds="125/1" oddsDecimal="126.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Ohio State" id="1413990298" odds="15/2" oddsDecimal="8.50" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Northwestern" id="1413990295" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Michigan State" id="1413990279" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Arizona State" id="1413990222" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Kansas" id="1413990263" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Stanford" id="1413990317" odds="80/1" oddsDecimal="81.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="East Carolina" id="1413990247" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Navy" id="1413990285" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="USC" id="1413990314" odds="15/2" oddsDecimal="8.50" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Alabama" id="1413990219" odds="4/1" oddsDecimal="5.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="UCF" id="1413990237" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Florida State" id="1413990251" odds="13/2" oddsDecimal="7.50" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="LSU" id="1413990267" odds="14/1" oddsDecimal="15.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Mississippi State" id="1413990283" odds="200/1" oddsDecimal="201.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Michigan" id="1413990278" odds="16/1" oddsDecimal="17.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Iowa State" id="1413990262" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Oklahoma" id="1413990299" odds="9/1" oddsDecimal="10.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Boston College" id="1413990230" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Western Kentucky" id="1413990341" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Texas Tech" id="1413990325" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="San Diego State" id="1413990309" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="SMU" id="1413990315" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Tulsa" id="1413990331" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Iowa" id="1413990261" odds="80/1" oddsDecimal="81.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Duke" id="1413990245" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Boise State" id="1413990229" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="West Virginia" id="1413990340" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="UCLA" id="1413990236" odds="50/1" oddsDecimal="51.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Rutgers" id="1413990308" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="NC State" id="1413990292" odds="100/1" oddsDecimal="101.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Miami (FL)" id="1413990276" odds="66/1" oddsDecimal="67.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Indiana" id="1413990260" odds="500/1" oddsDecimal="501.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Georgia" id="1413990252" odds="33/1" oddsDecimal="34.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Baylor" id="1413990228" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Washington State" id="1413990339" odds="80/1" oddsDecimal="81.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="TCU" id="1413990323" odds="80/1" oddsDecimal="81.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Louisiana Tech" id="1413990268" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="North Carolina" id="1413990291" odds="250/1" oddsDecimal="251.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    <participant name="Memphis" id="1413990275" odds="1000/1" oddsDecimal="1001.00" lastUpdateDate="2017-04-04" lastUpdateTime="00:51:59" handicap=""/>
    </market>
    </type>
    </class>
    <disclaimer>
    WHG (International) Ltd ("We/Us") of 6/1 Waterport Place, Gibraltar, owns the XML Feed Website ( the "Website") relating to information contained on its main trading website. By using the Website You agree to these full Terms of Use available at http://developer.williamhill.com
    </disclaimer>
    </williamhill>
    </response>
    </oxip>
```

Comment: I don't think `...->type['name']['NCAA']->...` works that way. Try using `SimpleXMLelement::xpath()`.

Comment: The below statement works fine. But I can't access the [index] for the < type > group. response->williamhill->class->type->market[0]participant[5]['name'];

Comment: Perhaps using children() might access the 2nd node?